# how do I enable scrolling in Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I open cmd.exe and I wanted to see my IP address. So I typed in ipconfig but then all the output does not fit in the CMD window, so I can't scroll up and actually see the important stuff.

So how do I... "enable"... scrolling? I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: There should be a scroll bar on the right side, a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: Command prompt is out-dated, dear... Use Windows PowerShell when you're on Vista or above...

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/keyboard-ninja-scrolling-the-windows-command-prompt-with-only-the-keyboard/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get to the properties you're looking for either by right-clicking the icon/shortcut you use to open the command prompt, or by left-clicking the icon in the top left corner of the command window.

In Properties, go to the Layout tab and increase Screen buffer size: Height to some big number like 1000.

On Windows XP, If you do it that last way, after clicking OK, it will ask if you want to make the settings the new default. Some variation on all that likely exists in Windows 7.

Comment: ohhh... That is what screen buffer size is for. I was looking through the Properties for a "scroll-bar" and I changed the window size, but its the buffer size that does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: For systems newer than XP, **Shift + RightClick** displays the same menu like in XP systems.

Answer (score 21):

1. Right-click on the command prompt window's title bar
2. Select "Properties" and go to the "Layout" tab
3. Under "Screen Buffer Size" increase the height to about 1000

Answer (score 4):

From the keyboard:

press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> altogether, then <kbd>E</kbd> , <kbd>L</kbd>

Now the arrow keys can be used to scroll through the output. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to normal mode.

Comment: This is an OEM dependent feature, i.e. on my Czech Windows after alt+space the menu is `Úpr_a_vy` > `Po_s_unout`, so `A, S` has to follow instead `E, L` (the underscored character in the menu hints the shortcut).

Answer (score 2):

I'm on XP at the moment, and scrolling seems to work fine!

Anyways if all else fails you could always redirect the output of the command to a text file?

```
ipconfig > result.txt
```

just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the title bar of the command window and select properties and select tab layout. A scroll bar will be shown when screen buffer size is bigger then the windows size.

To see the defaults, right click on the title bar of the command window and select defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the unixutils package for Windows and use the less utility like so:

```
ipconfig | less
```

This will limit the output to 1 screenful at a time.  Hit spacebar to continue, or use the cursor keys. q to quit.

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Less is more, or something equally pithy...

ipconfig | more

...will work just as well without having to install anything extra!

Comment: If you also want horizontal scrolling, rather than line-wrapping, use `your_command | less -S`

Answer (score 1):

to enable scrolling bar on **cmd** prompt, you only need to follow this instructions to  achieve your aim.

1. first thing open **cmd** prompt by inserting **cmd** word in dialog **run**
2. on title bar of **cmd** prompt click **righ_click**
3. after clicked **right_click** a list of features will appear, then select **properties** option
4. if selected **properties** option, then click **layout** section
5. in layout option set maximum value of **height** (9999) that existed in "**screen buffer size**" section
6. after click **ok** to save the last modifications

after following this steps you will see scroll bar in right side of cmd prompt, then you can scrolling as you want.
**good luck**.

Answer (score -2):

The quickest way is to grab the corners of the window with your mouse cursor and drag to resize it. You should then see the contents of the window.

Comment: That doesn't work. I can't resize past a certain point.. and the scrollbar doesn't show up so I can't see all of the content anyway.