# How to Increase Windows 7 Terminal/Command Prompt FPS

Tags: command-line, terminal, scrolling

Does anyone know how to increase the frames-per-second of the Windows 7 terminal?  When I am scrolling in it, it is hard to read the text because it seems to skip down an entire line before re-rendering it.  Is there any way to make it scroll as smoothly as other windows do, so that you can actually read the text while scrolling, aka. have it go pixel by pixel instead of line by line?

This question has been incorrectly marked as a potential duplicate of [how do I enable scrolling in Windows command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/161125/how-do-i-enable-scrolling-in-windows-command-prompt).  This question is asking about how to improve the smoothness of scrolling in the command prompt.  The suggested duplicate is asking about how to enable scrolling, not how to improve it.

Comment: Windows command windows always scroll by line. Other than answer added by @Tom; you may also check if correct display drivers are installed. Without correct display drivers, you will see lag while scrolling or moving windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I enable scrolling in Windows command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/161125/how-do-i-enable-scrolling-in-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: @harrymc Nope, not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Sandeep The correct drivers are installed - this is how the Windows command line has always worked on all the computers I use.  I was just hoping that someone knew of a way to improve this in some control panel or registry setting.

Comment: The Windows feature that you are asking about is a console.  It is not a terminal, nor is it a command prompt.  Terminals are what consoles evolved from; and command prompts are things displayed on consoles by command interpreters.

Comment: @JdeBP: Thank you for being so pedantic and unhelpful, but unfortunately, you'll see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe that the name of the program in question is, in fact, "Command Prompt", as is also indicated by the fact that it is titled that in the start menu.  I will agree, however, that it is somewhat of a misnomer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a CMD related problem.

Go to Control panel, then find the mouse settings-page and go to the scroll tab.

There you can adjust how much you scroll horizontally and vertically.

*Another solution would be to use the scrollbar on the right-hand side of the CMD window.*

Comment: That improved it, thanks!  But the lowest I can bring it down to is 1 line per scroll, not one pixel.  This applies whether I use the scroll wheel on the mouse or drag the scroll bar; it only ever moves by, at minimum, one line.  I'd like to figure out a way to get it to move in one pixel increments so that I can read the text while it is moving.

Comment: Glad it helped a bit, but I do believe you can't scroll by pixels, only by lines. CMD itself does not provide any customization to this. This is windows itself. I do not know if there is any kind of third party software that allows customization. You could try making the CMD window bigger? you do this by right-clicking on the top bar of a CMD window and go into properties. There you will find settings to resize the CMD window. What exactly are you trying to do? why do you need to read inside a CMD window? would be helpful with some context.